# nginx wordpress subdomain redirects to root

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx, subdomain, redirect

I have an issue with a Wordpress installation on a subdomain and seems to be redirecting to the root website. When first accessing the subdomain (blog.example.com), it works fine but the second time, it seems to redirect to the root URL (example.com).

Here is the Nginx code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/blog-au;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name blog.example.com;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    } 
}
```

Please do let me know if you need anymore information from me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the WordPress general configuration - do you have the correct URL listed for SITE and HOME?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have the correct URL for SITE and HOME.